# How to fetch the dynamically created element by its ID in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Initially adding the element statically like below:

```
<td valign="top" id="description_div">
    *<table class="des_box" id="comment_div">
        <tr><td class="head" id=file_comments> The function comments </td></tr> 
        <tr><td class="comment" id="test_point_comment_info"></td></tr> 
        </table>*
</td>
```

Dynamically adding the element as below :

```
$("#description_div").append(
    '<table class="des_box1" id=comment_div><tr><td class="head" id=file_comments> The function comments </td></tr><tr><td class="comment" id=test_point_comment_info_' + id + '></td></tr> </table>')
```

Now, when I try to fetch the element by its id (that is by "comment_div") ... I am not able to retrieve the dynamically created element. But able to fetch the static element by using `$("#comment_div")`

I am trying to do following on the element :

```
$("#comment_div").show();
```

tried .live() ....but was not able to fetch the dynamic element.

```
$("#comment_div").live().show();
```

check box code :

```
<li><input type="checkbox"  name="comment" />Comment</li>
```

actual functions where am trying to fetch the element:

```
$("#checkbox_div input:checkbox").click(function() {
var division = "#" + $(this).attr('name') + "_div";
$(division).show();
}

function SetCheckboxes(checkbox_data) {
    //SetCookie('pre_checkbox', "1111111111111111")
    var checkbox_data = GetCookie('pre_checkbox');
    if (checkbox_data == null) {
        SetCookie('pre_checkbox', "1111111111111111")
        checkbox_data = GetCookie('pre_checkbox');
    }

    checkbox_array = new Array("owner", "test_time", "bp", "single_use", "num_of_test", "pause", "clearall", "clearclass", "clearmax", "closeall", "qeinbat", "m_lint","geck","header","comment","feature");
    for ( i = 0; i < checkbox_data.length; i++) {
        var checkbox_name = checkbox_array[i];
        var value = checkbox_data[i];
        var division = "#" + checkbox_name + "_div";
        
        
        if (checkbox_name=="geck" || checkbox_name=="header" || checkbox_name== "comment" || checkbox_name=="feature"){
            console.log("entering_loop_as_expected")
            if (value == "1") {
            //alert("1");
            $("#checkbox_div input[name='" + checkbox_name + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
            
            $(division).show();
            
            
        } else {
            
            
            $(division).hide();
        }
                    continue;
                    
            }
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Did you really leave off the quotes in `$(#comment_div)`?  If so, you would have seen an error in the console. It will save you a great deal of time to keep the console open while developing code.

Comment: @Pointy ... No I have used the quotes in my code ...... updated my post ..... i am able to fetch the static elements properly .... but not the dynamic ones ...

Comment: Don't use `.live()` Ref.  http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Something like this needs a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ since we can't be sure what's not working on your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `quotes`, also ensure you try to access them before they are added to `DOM`, e.g they will not be available on DOM ready if they are added on some button click. I think you forgot to give value of id, I have made a live demo.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wRLmQ/1/)**

```
$("#checkbox_div input:checkbox").click(function() {
var division = "#" + $(this).attr('name') + "_div";    
$(division).show();
});

id=1;
$("#description_div").append('<table class="des_box1" id="comment_div"><tr><td class="head" id="file_comments"> The function comments </td></tr><tr><td class="comment" id="test_point_comment_info_' + id + '"></td></tr> </table>');
```

**Edit** based on comments and fiddle being provided.

You have few problems with html in the demo

1. Your html starts with td instead of table
2. You do not enclose the ids with quotes
3. You are assigning same id to more then one element, instead assign a
   common class and use that.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTNQT/5/)**, **Problem here are not dynamic element but the wrong HTML / Script**

*Html*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" id="description_div">
            <table class="des_box" id="comment_div1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="head" id="file_comments">The function commentszz</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="comment" id="test_point_comment_info"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="checkbox_div">
    <input type="checkbox" name="des" />Comment
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$("#description_div").append(
    '<table class="des_box" id="comment_div2"><tr><td class="head" id=file_comments> The function comments </td></tr><tr><td class="comment" id=test_point_comment_info_' + 'id' + '></td></tr> </table>');

$(document).on("click", "#checkbox_div input:checkbox", function () {
    var division = "." + $(this).attr('name') + "_box";
    $(division).show();
});
```

If you have to use **same id for more than one element with is wrong** you can use attribute selector. First correct the html by enclosing td within tr and table tag.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTNQT/7/)**

```
$(document).on("click", "#checkbox_div input:checkbox", function(){
    var division = "[id=" + $(this).attr('name') + "_div]";
    $(division).show();
});
```

Comment: Show us complete code or it would be better if you can make a fiddle

Comment: i have used the quotes properly in my code ..... i have updated the post as well ...... am able to fetch the static elements but not the dynamic ones ...

Comment: Its important to when when you access dynamic elements, currently your code does not give any clue about that.

Comment: ....Please check the fiddle now ..... its not fetching the dynamic content that is added .... it only fetches the static content.....[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTNQT/3/)

Comment: yeah there was a duplication of the id which was causing the problem ........ I tried to fetch these elements by their class name .... now it works perfectly as i wanted..... thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is what you wanted but it has been depreciated, you now need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on("click", "#checkbox_div input:checkbox", function(){
    //Your code here.
});
```

Using document for your `selector` with `.on` will allow you to bind events to dynamically created elements.  This is the only way I've found to do it when the DOM elements don't exist prior to execution.

I do this in a dynamically created table that is sort-able and works great.

EDIT:

Here is an example.  Click the button to add a `div` then click the `div` to get it's contents.

http://jsfiddle.net/FEzcC/1/

Comment: $(division).show(); function at 2 to 3 places ...and every where its not handled by checkbox click function ..... so what i need exactly is that .... i should be able to fetch the dynamically created element ..... jus like as we do for $("#someelement") ...

Comment: @user2569524 See the update with the fiddle, it's a basic example of adding `div`s and getting their contents.

Comment: can you please check the link and my question in the comments of the code  here ..... [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FEzcC/3/)

Comment: @user2569524 Maybe my new fiddle answers your question.  I noticed the bug after I first posted it.  I ditched the first box and just dynamically added like your function comment.

Comment: @user2569524 Also on your question.  Use the selector `this` in your events rather than trying to make a variable to get and store it. Using `this` will allow you access the element that triggered the event.

Comment: I cannot do that as am jus fetching that element ...with out any action being performed on it like click or anything...as in ..... i am checking the box somewhere ....and trying to fetch the dynamically added element by its id .... or in some function i am trying to fetch it directly. using like this ...$("#someelemntid")

Answer (score 0):

What is `id` value in `+ id +`, `id` is `undefined` in current context. I have put it in single quote and its working fine.

Update: You are using same `id` `comment_div` for static and dynamic content, `id` should be unique in `DOM`. Use `class` instead of `id` for multiple elements

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/ZTNQT/4/)

Comment: ...in this jsFiddle ..... upon click of the checkbox ..... it populates the static content .... could you please let me know how to fetch the dynamic content ...... i should be able to fetch the dynamically created element ..... jus like as we do for $("#someelement")

Comment: Use `on` as suggested by @defaultNINJA , jsFiddle updated, What do you mean by dynamic content? Do you want to fetch content from other page? if yes then you have to use `AJAX`

Comment: its not fetching the dynamic content that is added .... it only fetches the static content.....[link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTNQT/3/)

Comment: Because you are using same `id` for static and dynamic, use `class` instead, answer and jsFiddle link updated http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/ZTNQT/4/

Comment: agreed ...we are fetching the dynamic content upon click of checkbox .... but how do we fetch it like we do for static elements .... just like $("#someid")   .... pls check the comments in the followign link [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FEzcC/3/)

Comment: Use `alert($('#2').text())` after adding dynamic content. `alert($('#1').text())` will not work because you are initializing `id` with 1 `var id = 1;`